# A buffer overrun error happened at CascadeTraining.exe

Tags: c++, opencv

I am training `cascadeclassifier` and a weird problem happened. It happened at  `tempStage->write( fs, Mat() );` in the following code.

```
        CvCascadeBoost* tempStage = new CvCascadeBoost;
        // save current stage
        char buf[10];
        sprintf(buf, "%s%d", "stage", i );
        filename = dirName + buf + ".xml";
        FileStorage fs( filename, FileStorage::WRITE );
        if ( !fs.isOpened() )
        {
            cout << "Current stage can not be written, because file " << filename
                    << " can not be opened." << endl;
            return false;
        }
        fs << FileStorage::getDefaultObjectName(filename) << "{";
        tempStage->write( fs, Mat() );
        fs << "}";
```

The OpenCV error is

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (No element name has been given) in unknown func
tion, file D:\Lib\OpenCV_Lib_2.4.6\include\opencv2/core/ope
rations.hpp, line 2908
```

What could be wrong? When I check fs, it has a lot of unable to read memory messages as the in the attached fig.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible buffer overrun here: `char buf[10]; sprintf(buf, "%s%d", "stage", i );`  If that integer is more than 5 digits, you've overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

the signature of `CvCascadeBoost::write` is:

```
void CvCascadeBoost::write( FileStorage &fs, const Mat& featureMap ) const
```

and you passed a empty matrix to it, which should be wrong.

Comment: I found the problem at FileStorage. Previously, I was using the source files and making my own exe program. Now I used the opencv_trainedclassifier.exe from bin folder and it works. I am still checking why FileStorage has problem.

Comment: Hi, does `opencv_trainedclassifier.exe` came with source code?